# NASM - Segmentation fault in loop

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, nasm

i got two similar loops, in which i write an address to eax and then from eax to a data-segment. The first first loop is working, the second loop returns a segfault. Why is the second loop wrong and the first not!?

```
section .data
n1: db 1
n2: db 1
```

[...]

```
n_1_1:
mov eax,one
mov [n1],eax
jmp DIG2

 n_2_1:
 mov eax,one
 mov [n2],eax        ; segfault
 jmp DISP2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db` declares a *byte* (8 bits), which isn't enough to hold `eax` (32 bits). Declare every variable so that it has enough space to hold the largest value you will try to write to / read from it.

For example:

```
; declare n1 and n2 as doublewords with initial values of 1
n1: dd 1
n2: dd 1
```

---

As for why one of them crashes and the other doesn't; it's hard to say from the code you've shown and not knowing the execution environment. But the second write overwrites 1 byte further into unallocated space (by the looks of it), which could be enough to make it crash even though the first write didn't cause a crash.